# How to set up a default layout in nest.js using Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, handlebars.js, nestjs

I'm just starting with nest.js having some previous experience with node and express.

I'm trying to set up a default layout for my partials and response renders. Here's my `main.ts`:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as hbs from 'hbs';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

    app.setBaseViewsDir(__dirname + '/views');
    hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
    app.setViewEngine('hbs');

    await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I have a feeling that there should be a default layout defined somewhere in that code but I have no idea how to proceed. My Google-fu has failed me, so can anyone give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
app.set('view options', { layout: 'index' });
```

You still need to use `@Render('valid-layout')` on all controllers and the provided layout name must be valid. It will just be overwritten by your default layout.

Comment: For anyone running a newer NestJS version do as:
app.setLocal('view options', { layout: 'layout' });

Answer (score 3):

This worked on a NestExpressApplication:

Import handlebars:

```
import * as hbs from 'hbs';
import { join } from 'path';
```

setting hbs as viewEngine a

```
app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
app.setViewEngine('hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(join(__dirname, '..', '/views/partials'));
```

Worked also with helpers:

```
hbs.handlebars.helpers = {
...require('handlebars-helpers')()
};
```